# Class instantiation function

Tags: c#

Hello am trying to learn C#, I came across this code from a C# tutorial:

```
Public Class A()
{
    Public A () : this(capacity:10) 
    {
    }

    public int capacity 
    {
        get { return _buffer.length;}
    }
}
```

I just did not understand why he used `:` between `Public A ()` and `this(capacity:10)`.

I did not know what to search for on Google 
so I decided to ask here.

My question is: what is this used for and why?

Comment: Personally, I would try harder figuring it out, before asking on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code provided *doesn't compile*. Probably, the code be something like this:

```
  // lower case for "public" and "class" 
  public class A {
    // _buffer is addressed in "capacity" property, let it be an array 
    private int[] _buffer = new int[10];

    // this constructor is mandatory for the code below
    public A(int capacity) {
    }

    // Now, your question:
    // "this(capacity: 10)" calls the costructor above 
    // "public A(int capacity)"
    // while passing the "capacity" parameter by its name
    public A () : this(capacity: 10)
    {
    }

    public int capacity {
    get {
      return _buffer.Length;
    }
  }
```

If I *guessed right* `this(capacity: 10)` is a call of the constructor `public A(int capacity)` while passing `capacity` by *name*

Comment: now I get it , thank you